# T-SQL - get count of joined entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder how better to write the following query to Microsoft SQL Server.

I have three tables: `surveys`, `survey_presets` and `survey_scenes`. They have the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[surveys](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [caption] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [creation_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[survey_presets](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [survey_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [preset_id] [int] NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[survey_scenes](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [survey_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [scene_id] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

Both `survey_presets` and `survey_scenes` have foreign keys on `surveys` for `survey_id` column.

Now I want to select all surveys with the count of corresponding presets and scenes for each. Here is the "pseudo-query" of what I want:

```
SELECT
    surveys.*,
    COUNT(survey_presets, where survey_presets.survey_id = surveys.id), 
    COUNT(survey_scenes, where survey_scenes.survey_id = surveys.id)
FROM surveys
ORDER BY suverys.creation_time
```

I can do a mess with `SELECT DISTINCT`, `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, etc., but I'm new to T-SQL and I doubt my query will be optimal in any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the counting in subqueries to avoid cartesian products. As you might have a few matching rows in `presets` and also a few in `scenes` resulting count might be multiplied. You might write simple join query and avoid the multiplication by counting `distinct survey_presets.id` and `distinct survey_scenes.id` though.

```
SELECT
    surveys.*,
    isnull(presets_count, 0) presets_count,
    isnull(scenes_count, 0) scenes_count
FROM surveys
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT survey_id,
         count(*) presets_count
    FROM survey_presets
   GROUP BY survey_id
) presets
  ON surveys.id = presets.survey_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT survey_id,
         count(*) scenes_count
    FROM survey_scenes
   GROUP BY survey_id
) scenes
  ON surveys.id = scenes.survey_id
ORDER BY surveys.creation_time
```

**How it works**

You can introduce a special kind of subquery called `derived table` to FROM section of your query. Derived table is defined as normal query enclosed in parenthesis and followed by table alias. It cannot use any column from outer query, but can expose columns you use in ON section to join derived table to main body of the query.

In this case derived table simply count rows grouped by id; joins connect the counts to surveys.

Comment: Good explanation. Though I found a little bug: if no presets or scenes are associated with the survey, corresponding count is equal to NULL, not zero. Would you please suggest how to fix that?

Comment: Oh, and this is not a bug. This is how left join works, substituting nulls for each requested column when a matching row cannot be found.

Comment: Nice. Too bad it's not working in EntityDataSource. But this is a different question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT surveys.ID, surveys.caption, surveys.creation_time,
count(survey_presets.survey_id) as survey_presets,
count(survey_scenes.survey_id)  as survey_scenes
FROM surveys
LEFT OUTER JOIN survey_presets on survey_presets.survey_id = surveys.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN survey_scenes  on survey_scenes.survey_id  = surveys.id
GROUP BY surveys.ID, surveys.caption, surveys.creation_time
ORDER BY suverys.creation_time
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "suverys.creation_time" could not be bound. - I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: suverys.creation_time is not what is in my answer  try as in the answer surveys.creation_time

Comment: I fixed the typo, but now it has the same error as for @Parado. It gives both `presets` and `scenes` count the value of their product.

Comment: Yes the double join results in double counting.  Since you have and accepted answer I am not going to fix it.